# Tomcat equivalent to Wildfly Deployment-Overlay

Tags: maven, tomcat, wildfly, java-ee-8, web-fragment

I'm creating a web-fragment project that I want to include in all of our already existing webapps, but I don't want to alterate the current webapps changing pom ecc.

I recently found about the Wildfly Deployment-Overlay and it works very good, now we have a webapp that runs under Tomcat and I can't find any equivalent to the Wildfly Deployment-Overlay.

At the moment I use this script to create a wildfly overlay using the jboss-cli.bat:

`deployment-overlay add --name=testOverlay --content=/META-INF/web-fragment.xml=C:/wildfly-18.0.1.Final/standalone/configuration/web-fragment.xml,/WEB-INF/lib/test-fragment-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar=C:/wildfly-18.0.1.Final/standalone/configuration/test-fragment-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --deployments=*mywebapp.war --redeploy-affected`

I hope to find some equivalent in Tomcat, or at least another way to the same thing, does Tomcat support this kind of deployment?